# DevExpress - Keep multi-selection on mouse click

Tags: wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I have a table, where in the first column I want to show a checkbox (currently of type `CheckEdit`) which enables the user to select/deselect items, and their name. Currently I have the following:

```
<dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" LastChildFill="True">
            <dxe:CheckEdit IsChecked="{Binding Path=RowData.DataContext.IsSelected}"
                           DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                           Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=RowData.DataContext.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            BorderThickness="0" />
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I have enabled multi-selection on the table, and I want it simply that if the user clicks one of the checkboxes, all of the selected checkboxes get the new value, and all of the rows stay selected.

What happenes now is that the `CheckEdit`-element that was clicked, gets a new value just as it should, all others remain unchanged, and the selection changes to only that specific row where the user clicked.

I have played around with `GotFocus`, `PreviewMouseDown` and  `MouseDown`. None really worked as I want.

How can I get this behaviour?